# How to use wordpress $wpbd with custom table?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-database

my friends.

I'm creating a custom php page on my wordpress website where I need to read and update a custom table. I'm using **$wpdb** class but I get no result when I use the table I create (the $result value stays *null*). With wordpress tables, it works fine and return the results. The problem is how to use my table...

This is everything that I tryed (the table name is **wp_test**):
`$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT test_id, test_cli, test_URL FROM {$wpdb->wp_test}");`

`$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT test_id, test_cli, test_URL FROM {$wpdb->test}");`

`$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT test_id, test_cli, test_URL FROM $wpdb->wp_test");`

``` $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT test_id, test_cli, test_URL FROM ``wp_test``"); ``` (with only one backticks)

`$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT test_id, test_cli, test_URL FROM wp_test");`

If I use a wordpress table, it returns the values:
`$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} LIMIT 10" );`

Please, can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Show full code with where you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug the issue is to print the raw SQL on the front and then run the query manually copying and pasting to the MySQL console.

Or you can try logging the last DB error with the below snippet.

```
$wpdb->suppress_errors(false);
// execute query here
if($wpdb->last_error !== '') :
    $wpdb->print_error();
endif;
```